# Layout_weight not distributing correctly with ScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to create a layout where I have a fixed size ScrollView tucked away on the right side of the screen and then a LinearLayout fills the remaining screen space.  Like so:

```
<---------------------------LinearLayout---------------------------><----ScrollView---->
```

Within the ScrollView is another LinearLayout that I dynamically add TextViews to.  Here's what I currently have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:baselineAligned="false"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/chart"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#FF0000"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
</LinearLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="260dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#0000FF"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/meterList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#00FF00"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

I read that setting the width to 0dp and weight to 1 SHOULD have it fill up the remaining part of the screen, but instead it is squished with the ScrollView taking up 90% of the screen.  What's weird is that my LinearLayout within the ScrollView is only taking up half of the space in it.  Since I color coded it, here's what it looks like:

```
<--Red--><----------------Green----------------><----------------Blue---------------->
```

Once a View has been dynamically added all of the blue background should be covered up like this:

```
<------------------------------Red------------------------------><-------Green------->
```

None of this is making any sense...

edit: Since this seems relevant now I should mention that this layout is inflated by my Fragment.  This Fragment then attaches to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/clearPrefs"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="DEBUG" >
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_chart"
        android:name="...GraphFragment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What is the parent of your LinearLayout and ScrollView?

Comment: @RomainGuy I just edited my post.  SO cut some of it out.  This layout is inflated by a Fragment and then attached to a different layout if that helps.

Comment: @Atlos Your layout works for me.  You should probably create a simple project that utilizes only this layout, to check if the issue is from this layout, or from your fragment + other layouts. (also, 260dp is a large portion of the screen for some screen sizes).

Comment: @ab11 I just edited my post again.  The layout is inflated by a Fragment and then attaches to another layout.